Getting Error "Worker was Destroyed" while loading large sized Pdf
I'm using "ng2-pdf-viewer": "9.1.5" version
I'm getting Error "Worker was Destroyed" in (error) handling function provided to component from pdf.mjs.
I wanted to say that it is not getting every time replicated, for me i was trying to load the PDF file around 1.25GB from the server URL of the file also it has 1303 pages.
Also even after this error text, file content chunk is getting downloaded as normal, File gets shown after whole content gets downloaded.
For the User convenience we are showing error to the User, but here if we think as user perspective it is wrong as file content download is still in process.
Can any one have faced the same issue, I'm looking for the actual RCA where why the Worker is getting Destroyed.
any detail/help is appreciable like what could be the RCA is it document Size, network latency, tab memory usage?
from any one.
Thanks
